# Spring Tools 4 with Spring Boot, Java 11 and Tomcat 9

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, spring-boot-starter

I come from Eclipse and I'm starting my first project in Spring (Boot). I'd like to use JDK 11.0.17 and Tomcat 9.0.31 as I do for my projects in Eclipse. That's what the sysadmin gave me to deploy my apps so I can't switch to anything else.

I download the newest Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse (4.18.0) and create a new Spring Starter Project. Default values are type "Gradle - Groovy", Java Version "17" and packaging "Jar", but I change them to "Maven", "11" and "War", respectively. I don't see any place where I can configure my Tomcat. I click Next, leave the field Spring Boot Version as it is (3.0.5) and click Finish.

It creates a Maven project, but Java Version is still 17 everywhere (JRE System Library, pom.xml). When I go to Boot Dashboard and start the demo project, I get Java Version 17.0.6 and Tomcat 10.1.7 in the output.

I try to change that manually:

- Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > 17 to 11
- Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > its 17.0.6 to my jdk 11.0.17
- Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > add my Tomcat 9.0.31
- Project > Properties > Java Build Path > its JavaSE-17 to my jdk-11.0.17
- Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level > 17 to 11
- Project > Properties > Project Facets > Java > 17 to 11
- Project > Properties > Targeted Runtimes > (I can't seem to do anything in Uninstall Facets...)
- pom.xml > properties > java.version > 17 to 11
  Then Clean Project and Update Maven Project.

Now when I go to Boot Dashboard and start the demo project, I get the exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0` which complains that it was expecting Java 17 but got Java 11.

I'm stuck with no more apparent options. Is Spring Boot supposed to work under a specific version so I should download an older Spring Tool Suite compatible with Java 11? I guess I'm doing/understanding something wrong.

Comment: Spring Boot 3 and up have as a minimum requirement Java17 and Tomcat 10. So that combination you have simply won't work. You need either Spring Boot 3, Java17 and Tomcat10 or Spring Boot 2.7, Java11/17 and Tomcat 9.

Comment: Hello, as you are using maven the best (and only place) where you should define your Spring Boot version is spring-boot-starter-parent definition. Current would be 3.0.5 and the older one 2.7.10

Comment: You can generate pom.xml using this: https://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, Spring Boot 3 has a minimum dependency on Java 17, that is why the tooling configures the created project to use Java 17 all across the place.

Please select the latest Spring Boot 2.7 version, Maven as a build environment, Java 11, and the WAR packaging and you should be good to go.

Comment: This was really confusing for me. They should show the page where you pick the Spring Boot Version before or next to the Java Version, not after, and then limit the Java Version choices based on the Spring Boot Version you chose.